# openpyxl, changing row values to lowercase

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to make my values lowercase in my row.

i've tried making a change to this line`val = r[filter_col - 1].value`  such as adding `.lower()` to the end of it. I cannot seem to sitch the values in the column to lowercase.

Can anyone help with this?

code:

```
    for i,r in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
        if i==0:
            continue  # Of course, do not delete the header row
        rownum = i + 1  # when we use it, must by 1-indexed like Excel

        val = r[filter_col - 1].value
        if str(val) not in thePerson:
            delete_these.append(rownum)
```

Comment: What is the content of ```val = r[filter_col - 1].value```?  Print it out!  I think you will find it is an object reference rather than  a string.  Try ```val = r[filter_col - 1].value().lower()```

Comment: I printed it , it prints names like "Joe Louis" , need it in lowercase!  `val = r[filter_col - 1].value().lower()` got an error , "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Okay, if ```val = r[filter_col - 1].value``` results in a value such as 'Joe Louis' then should be able to convert to 'joe louis' by ```val = r[filter_col - 1].value.lower()```

Comment: i get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'` sigh. Also there are values that print that are "None" , not sure if that would effect this.

Comment: Yes, that is your problem  At some point your val is None which is not a string object and therefore has no .lower() method/attribute associated with it. You need to detect val is None and make some adjustments to your code.

Comment: Please reduce your code to focus on the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

`r[filter_col - 1]` is the cell.

`r[filter_col - 1].value` is the cell's value.

In order to change the value of the cell, you need to assign a new value to it: `r[filter_col - 1].value = r[filter_col - 1].value.lower()`.

As *itprorh66* pointed out, sometimes the value is `None`. The value needs to be of type `str` to call its `lower()` method. So you need to check beforehand, like so:

```py
if isinstance(r[filter_col - 1].value, str):
   r[filter_col - 1].value = r[filter_col - 1].value.lower()
val = r[filter_col - 1].value
```

You can of course refactor that code, but there you go.